# WPF InteractionRequest not working after Updating Prism 6.2.0 to 8.0

Tags: wpf, prism, updating

I have updated my WPF project build with Prism 6.2.0 to Prism 8.0. I am using .NET Framework 4.7.

I use `InteractionRequest` in a lot of places within my application in order to open a popup to gather user information. After updating the project, I get this error:

> The type or namespace 'InteractionRequest<>' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference or a using directive?.

I have added the using `Prism.Interactivity`.

Does any one know how to fix this? Is `InteractionRequest` deprecated in Prism 8.0? And if it is, how do I substitute that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InteractionRequest` and `PopupWindowAction` API was replaced with a new dialog service in [Prism 7.2.0.1367](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367). The reasons for this are covered in the following GitHub issues:

- [[WPF] Interactivity improvements](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/864)
- [A New IDialogService for WPF](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1666)

To quote Brian Lagunas the [release notes](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367):

> Currently, the only way to show any type of dialog with Prism is by using the PopupWindowAction in combination with System.Windows.Interactivity. [...] It's over complex, highly verbose, difficult to implement, and is very limited. [...]
>
> Instead, I created a new IDialogService API that will replace the PopupWindowAction altogether. This service will allow developers to show any dialog they want either modal, or non-modal, and have complete control over their dialog logic.

You can refer to the [dialog service documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html) to learn how to use it and migrate. Please also note that Prism 8 adds support for multiple dialog window hosts, this is not supported in Prism 7.x.